# Resizing JavaFX WebView

Tags: webview, javafx

I'm attempting to embed a WebView into a BorderPane as it's middle component. My app starts initially in an unmaximized mode. If I maximize the application, the webview will resize accordingly, but the html & css content will not fill the whole area (it is centered in the WebView). How would I go on fixing this? I've tried to call impl_reapplyCss() and friends, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I ran a simple test and could not reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Sorry, it was a stupid mistake that the WebView content (my own HTML & CSS) wasn't actually even maximized to fit width.